# azure continuous export - never persists the container

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I can't seem to get the continuous export job working properly, and I'm wondering if this is an issue.  The behaviour of this field (red arrow) is different that the three above it.   In that when the container is selected, the container name is displayed, but when you revisit the configuration, the name is missing.  Is this a "feature" or a bug.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug.  you should submit this as feedback directly inside the portal via the feedback tool (there should be a smiley face icon in the toolbar up in the right hand side by where it shows your username/etc)

If your export is working, then it is saving the info and just not restoring it if you go to edit it.